# Controller context doesn't contain view model data in custom model binder

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, model-binding

I'm trying to override default model binder for a single action method. Unfortunately when I call it using ajax post request, the controller's context object doesn't contain model's data.
Here is my js code:

```
            $http.post(url.GetProducts, { productSearchViewModel: model.criteria) }).success(function(data, status) {
                    if (data.Error == null) {
                        // some code
                    }
                }).finally(function() {
                    // some code
                });
```

My controller action method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AuthorizeOperation(OperationName = "GetProducts")]
    public ActionResult GetProducts([JsonBinder]ProductViewModel productSearchViewModel)
    {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
               // some code
    }
```

And the custom model binder code:

```
public class JsonBinderAttribute : CustomModelBinderAttribute
{
    public override IModelBinder GetBinder()
    {
        return new JsonModelBinder();
    }

    public class JsonModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public object BindModel(
            ControllerContext controllerContext,
            ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            try
            {
                var json = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request
                           .Params[bindingContext.ModelName];

                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
                    return null;

                // Swap this out with whichever Json deserializer you prefer.
                return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert
                       .DeserializeObject(json, bindingContext.ModelType);
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I remove the JsonBinder attribute, the productSearchViewModel value is correctly populated. If I leave it and debug it, the json in BindModel method is always null.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting the json value from the wrong place?  When I've written custom model binders, the value comes from bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

Comment: I found this example here. http://www.tomdupont.net/2009/08/mvc-json-model-binder.html
However, I've just tried the way you suggested and the value is still null.